# /var/cache/logwatch No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/logwatch line 633

Tags: debian, logwatch

Logwatch has been working perfectly until now. I read a tutorial that you shouldnt edit the config in the default place

/usr/share/logwatch

Instead you should move it to 
/etc/logwatch

So i did that and now i get this error

```
/var/cache/logwatch No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/logwatch line 633.
```

Does anyone know how to fix? Or should i just try removing the entry in /etc ?

Answer (score 9):

The advice given in /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf is quite right. However, after copying the logwatch.conf you may just want to deactivate line 30 in /etc/logwatch/logwatch.conf (or /etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf in some versions).

`# TmpDir = /var/cache/logwatch`

or, alternatively, create this directory with

`sudo mkdir /var/cache/logwatch`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Either that advice was wrong, or you misunderstood it.

You should leave the default configuration **in place**, but you should make **customisations** in **extra** files in `/etc/logwatch`.

You need to undo what you have done, and then add your own customisations in `/etc/logwatch`.

`logwatch` reads the configuration in `/usr/share/logwatch` first, and then it reads your customisations from `/etc/logwatch`, but it won't work if the former isn't there.

Comment: Also Ubuntu help about logwatch says that "Configuration shouldn't be edited in the install directory (/usr/share/logwatch). Copy logwatch.conf to /etc/logwatch before editing"... resulting in that error ("/var/cache/logwatch No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/logwatch line...").

Comment: Copying and moving are different.